# Why do not we have tag synonyms like they are on Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

For example, let's look at the tag `selenium2` on Stackoverflow. There is a synonym 'selenium-webdriver' When we are trying to find synonym for `selenium2` on sqa.stackexchange.com then there is no synonym for `selenium2`. Shouldn't tags have the same synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently do have some synonyms. You can review them at https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

As for differences between SO and SQA, we're two different sites, and our tags are not connected in any way. They don't have the same descriptions either.

If you have a certain reputation you can suggest synonyms on a tag's wiki, or at any time you can post on meta about them. If you're interested, you could compile a list of the popular SQA tags that have synonyms on SO and post that list on meta. Folks could suggest feedback for a few days, and then I or another diamond can enact those synonyms.

Comment: Ok, it's clear about differences between SO and SQA. I'd like to suggest synonym for selenium but don't have enough reputation. But if I found some more synonyms I definitely create new topic and I hope it will help organize tags. Thank you.

Comment: That's perfect. What you could even do is have a topic as a header, and 'answer' the 'question' with a pairing. People could voice their opinion by voting up and down, and with comments, and others could make suggestions too. If they reach a certain threshold and no complaints in the comments, I can add them and delete that answer, and we can continue to use the post.